# MongoTemplate Custom Config using Spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I was looking to change WriteResultChecking property of mongoTemplate whilst working on Spring boot app (2.0.5). I found out a way via extending AbstractMongoConfiguration as below.

I got the same working, however i found this approach a bit risky.
Saying this because this approach forced me to write a implementation for

```
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    return new MongoClient(host, port);
}
```

Now MongoClient is the central class to maintain connections with MongoDB and if i am forced to write implementation for the same, then i may be possibly missing out on optimizations that spring framework does.

Can someone please suggest any other optimal way of overriding some properties/behaviours without having to tinker too much ?

```
@Configuration
public class MyMongoConfigs extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {


    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String databaseName;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    private int port;


    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient(host, port);

    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return databaseName;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate myTemp = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
        **myTemp.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION);**
        return myTemp;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are in right direction. Using `AbstractMongoConfiguration` you override the configs that you need to customize and it's the right way to do it.  `AbstractMongoConfiguration` is still Spring Provided class, so the you don't have to worry about optimization, unless you mess with your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach:

```
package app.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.WriteResultChecking;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoConverter;

import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;

@Configuration
class ApplicationConfig {

  @Bean
  MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, MongoConverter converter) {
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
    mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY);
    mongoTemplate.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION);
    return mongoTemplate;
  }
}
```

I have figured this out by inspecting the source code of `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: Don't need to use MongoConverter only MongoDatabaseFactory as input parameter is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote CustomMongoTemplate which override method `find()` with added criteria to check if document has 'deletedAt' field;

Custom MongoTemplate:

```
public class CustomMongoTemplate extends MongoTemplate {
    public CustomMongoTemplate(MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory, MongoConverter mongoConverter) {
        super(mongoDbFactory, mongoConverter);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> List<T> find(Query query, Class<T> entityClass, String collectionName) {
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("deletedAt").exists(Boolean.FALSE));

        return super.find(query, entityClass, collectionName);
    }
```

Then create Bean in configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
//...
    @Bean(name = "mongoTemplate")
    CustomMongoTemplate customMongoTemplate(MongoDatabaseFactory databaseFactory, MappingMongoConverter converter) {
        return new CustomMongoTemplate(databaseFactory, converter);
    }
//...
}
```

And last thing - allow Spring to override default MongoTemplate bean. Add next thing to your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```